# Stable sorting without using sort libraries - Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I want to sort a list of words by word length but maintain the original order of words with same length (stable sorting).

For example:

```
words = ['dog', 'cat', 'hello', 'girl', 'py', 'book']
```

Should become

```
words = ['py', 'dog', 'cat', 'girl', 'book', 'hello']
```

I know this can be done easily with python's sorted function, which is stable:

```
sorted(words, key = lambda l:len(l))
```

But how would one do this efficiently without access to the library? I've been trying to brainstorm a solution and I'm thinking

1. Create a dict that will contain the index (key) and length (value) of each word in words
2. Maybe use a Counter to track how many instances of each length word there is (for this ex., would look like Counter({3: 2, 5: 1, 4: 2, 2: 1}))
3. Go through the dict looking for the minimum length of a word in counter (2 in my ex), and keep doing that for amt of times that length appears
4. Step 3 but moving onto next minimum in Counter

But this seems super inefficient. Could someone help with a better implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a nomral `bubble sorting` technique for this.

**Algo**

- Loop from 0 to `len(word)-1`
- Nested loop from `i+1` to `len(words)`
- compare if `words[i] > words[j]`
- Do swap, words[i] = words[j]

```
words = ['dog', 'cat', 'hello', 'girl', 'py', 'book']

# first loop
for i in range(len(words)-1):
    # second loop
    for j in range(i+1, len(words)):
        # swapping if first word is bigger than the second
        if len(words[i]) > len(words[j]):
            temp = words[i]
            words[i] = words[j]
            words[j] = temp
print(words)
```

**Output**

```
['py', 'cat', 'dog', 'girl', 'book', 'hello']
```

This solves your problem in the time complexity of `O(N*N)`. So kind of costly. But you can use it for a inputs of the length till `10^3`

Answer (score 0):

One solution, is to make dictionary `buckets`, where keys are length of the words (integer) and values are lists storing words of the same length. You can construct this dict in linear time.

Then traverse the dictionary from `0` to `max_bucket`, where `max_bucket` is maximal lenght of observed word:

```
words = ['dog', 'cat', 'hello', 'girl', 'py', 'book']

buckets = {}
max_bucket = -1
for w in words:
    buckets.setdefault(len(w), []).append(w)
    if len(w) > max_bucket:
        max_bucket = len(w)

out = [w for i in range(max_bucket+1) for w in buckets.get(i, [])]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['py', 'dog', 'cat', 'girl', 'book', 'hello']
```

Comment: I just tried this implementation but it doesn't keep it in stable order